# jQueryUi Datepicker wrap multiple months

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've been fiddling around with the jquery-ui.css file I downloaded to see if I could make multiple months look nice in a wrapped (rather than the default all horizontal) fashion and having trouble.  Has anyone been able to successfully make multiple months wrap nicely on the Datepicker?  I have to show 12 calendar months so I would like to wrap the months to display nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in charge a datepicker every three. This css code:

```
.ui-datepicker-group:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

You can see the result here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw98L851/10/